# A question about a line from Diving Bell And The Butterfly

Tags: plot-explanation, diving-bell-and-butterfly

There is a joke in *The Diving Bell and the Butterfly* talking about the main character being a heavy breather when he cannot speak to the phone. What's funny about that?

Comment: Could you add little more info like, approximate time where scene occurred, joke said by whom? the nurses or some other person?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The joke comes from "heavy breather".
See this definition from thefreedictionary:

> an anonymous telephone caller who imitates such sounds, as being
>   suggestive of sexual excitement